# Check if list of latitude, longitude are withing range

Tags: coordinate-systems, polygons

I'm having a problem

I would like to ask what the most efficient way is to check if latitude and longitude coordinates are inside a range (for example 100 meters) from a list of latitudes and longitude points.

For example I have this list of coordinates:

```
[[48.34483,51.16.24517],[48.484,16.2585],[48.361,51.87739419],[6.38477205,51.87745015],[48.3645,51.16.73167],[6.38391099,51.87755068],[48.3575,16.725],[6.38380232,51.87720004],[6.38376297,51.87708017],[6.38375183,51.87704018],[6.38373055,51.8769829]]
```

I would like that all points that are in a specific range (100m for example), to be somehow grouped.

Is there any way how I can indicate that for example from the above list:

`[48.484,16.2585],[48.361,51.87739419]` and `[48.3575,16.725]`

are in a radius of 100m ( distance between these points is less than 100m) and they should be groped,
and when they are grouped I would like to add additional Point within half of their distance.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem

Comment: @MattiP. Hmm I think it's not that :/

Comment: Are you assuming a spherical world?

Comment: Yes, these points are grom Geoserver